# ordinary power strips protections for power outlet IOT

Tags: power-electronics

I am trying to build some power outlet device based of [this](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/diy-smart-plug-using-esp8266) to built some thing like [this](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/BESTEK-2-Outlet-Travel-Power-Strip-with-2-4A-Dual-Smart-USB-Charging-Ports/PRD23BK5HS7YBUW):
[image]

also i like to add it some normal eclectic device protection ([ordinary power strips 220v/10A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_strip) for TV or refrigerator ) like this :

> Power strips often include a circuit breaker to interrupt the electric
>   current in case of an overload or a short circuit. Some power strips
>   provide protection against electrical power surges. Typical housing
>   styles include strip, rack-mount, under-monitor and direct plug-in.

so i found [this](https://circuitbest.com/over-voltage-and-under-voltage-protection/) or [this](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/mains-ac-overload-protection-circuit/) for overload protection circuit , and [some Over-Current-Protection](https://easyeda.com/avinashsingh1992/Over-Current-Protection) circuit and this as [surge protection](https://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/90219-build-a-simple-whole-house-surge-protector/) but not sure what is the proper circuit and protection for this kind usage and could combine them to do all in one circuit!.
so do those circuits fine for this usage?

So i asked here to know your viewpoints.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) we do not know what kind of protection circuit is in the devices you suggest. 2) it is unclear **why** protection is needed 3) there should be circuit breakers and ground fault protection in your house already. If not, add these first.

Comment: 4) in **my opionion** such "overload protection power strips" give a **false sense of security**. In practice, these devices don't do much. The (small) voltage peaks they can absorb can also be handled by most electrical equipment. When a real disaster happens like a direct lightning hit on your mains cables, these "protectors" do not offer enough protection. Your TV will be damaged anyway with or without such a protector.

Answer (score 0):

Normal surge protectors are 3 MOV's (Metal Oxide Varistors) between Live - Neutral, Live - Earth, Neutral - Earth, as well as some Y2 class capacitors in parrellel with the MOV's thrown in to soak up some of the mains noise to keep smaller spikes from tripping them

e.g. if your area is 240V mains, you might use 275V MOVs to clamp surges, just be aware that they can only survive so many surges before they need to be replaced

The fancier ones include a circuit breaker that can be reset, the good ones break both live and neutral, the ones you usually see for lower costs only break the live wire.

Some of the active surge protection circuits you showed may be better alternatives, however relays are usually much slower to switch than a surge that may damage things, that would be more for areas where prolonged brownouts or higher than spec voltages are expected for say half a minute or longer,